# Deriving the mean of the Gumbel Distribution

Tags: statistics, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, expectation

I'm trying to determine an expected value of a random variable related to the Gumbel/Extreme Value Type 1 distribution.  I think the answer follows the same process as expected value of the Gumbel itself, but I can't figure out the derivation of the expected value of the Gumbel.

I found [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=16&ved=0ahUKEwiSwP2OmcHNAhVDGx4KHZOyAEQ4ChAWCD0wBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maths.manchester.ac.uk%2F~saralees%2Fesol1.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEw7mHnbpRPiSYlwyuvJ00ZZY2whA&sig2=k0rgpd1aPdpNAg6o6s3nIQ&bvm=bv.125221236,d.dmo&cad=rja) a derivation, but there's a step in the middle where magic happens.  Need to understand what's going on there to see if I can apply it to my other problem.

Recall, the density of the Gumbel distribution is $f(x) = e^{-e^{-x}}e^x$.  The derivation at the link shows that

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x e^{-x} e^{-e^{-x}}dx = - \int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln y}e^{-y}dy\quad  [y=e^{-x}]\\
= -\frac{d}{d\alpha}\int_0^\infty y^\alpha e^{-y}dy\bigg|_{\alpha=0}\\
=-\frac{d}{d\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha+1)\bigg|_{\alpha=0}\\
=\Gamma'(1) = \gamma \approx 0.577...
$$

The jump from the first line to the second is the one I can't follow.  I've tried doing integration by parts on one or the other to demonstrate the equivalence, but I end up with a floating 1 or infinity.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the bracketed statement supposed to be $[y=e^{-x}]$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The step in question employs a trick called "differentiating under the integral."  The idea is to introduce a parameter in the integrand, and express the integrand as a derivative with respect to this parameter, then change the order of integration and differentiation (assuming certain regularity conditions hold).

Explicitly, suppose we let $f(y,\alpha) = y^\alpha e^{-y}.$  Then $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \alpha} = y^\alpha \log y \, e^{-y}.$$  Then letting $\alpha = 0$ gives us the integrand in the first line of the solution; hence $$-\int_{y=0}^\infty \log y \, e^{-y} \, dy = -\int_{y=0}^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\left[y^\alpha e^{-y}\right]_{\alpha = 0} \, dy = -\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \left[\int_{y=0}^\infty y^\alpha e^{-y} \, dy \right]_{\alpha = 0}.$$

Comment: Oh...I actually had the gist of differentiating under the integral, but was differentiating $y^\alpha$ as a power rule instead of an exponential.  But besides straightening me out, your answer explains the method really well.  Thanks!