# Estimation of parameter by the method of moments

Tags: integration, statistics, parameter-estimation

**Let $X_1,X_2,\dots X_n$ be a random sample from the density $$f(x;\theta)=e^{-(x-\theta)} e^{-e^{-(x-\theta)}}, \quad -\infty<x<\infty ,\quad -\infty<\theta<\infty$$
Find the method of moments estimator of $\theta$.**

***What I attempted:-***

Here $E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xe^{-(x-\theta)} e^{-{e^{-(x-\theta)}}}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x-\theta)e^{-(x-\theta)} e^{-{e^{-(x-\theta)}}}dx+\theta$.
The integral of the final expression can be written as \begin{equation}  
\begin{aligned} 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x-\theta)e^{-(x-\theta)} e^{-{e^{-(x-\theta)}}}dx&=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}t e^{-t} e^{-{e^{-t}}}dt \quad \mbox{where $t=x-\theta$}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \log y \hspace{1mm} e^{-y}dy \quad \mbox{where $y=e^{-t}$}\\
&=-\log y \hspace{1mm} e^{-y}|_0^{\infty}+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-y}}{y}dy
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I was not able to proceed beyond that. I don't think that the integral exist.

However, it can be shown that $e^{-X}$ is an exponential variate with mean $e^{-\theta}$. Is this information of any help?

Comment: yeah $$\int_0^\infty y^{-1}e^{-y}dy=\Gamma(0)$$ which is undefined

Comment: So ultimately $E(X)$ does not exist.

Comment: Yeah I think so. The integrand $e^{-x}\log(x)$ is undefined at $x=0$ Which I'm pretty sure implies divergence

Comment: This is a [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution) with scale parameter unity. So expected value of $X$ should turn out to be $\theta+\gamma$, $\gamma$ being the Euler-Mascheroni constant, as elaborated in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use integration by parts on $\int_0^\infty \log (y)e^{-y}dy$. Look closely and you'll find that integration by parts leads to the indeterminate form $-\infty +\infty$. In fact the integral 
$$\int_0^\infty \log( y) e^{-y}dy$$
converges; its value is [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1838415/215011) to be the opposite of the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: Note also that you've lost a minus sign in your calculation, occurring during the substitution $y=e^{-t}$.